# Better way of prefix matching in a short string in Go: strings or regexp

Tags: regex, string, go, match, prefix

I know that the string I'll get will be short ( < 50 chars). 
I also know that my substring will be matched exactly once (or won't be matched at all), and that it will appear de facto at the beginning of the string.

I cannot decide whether to use `strings.Contains`, e.g., `strings.Contains("123-ab-foo", "123-ab")`, or `regexp`.  I want the fastest way obviously.

Example of the use case:

```
if strings.Contains(current_string, MY_CONST){
     // do smth 
 }
```

Comment: RegExp is always slower than pure string comparison. RE's advantage is its flexibility. That said... why didn't you just [benchmark it](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks)?

Comment: because I actually hoped to see how to write the best solutions for both (as with .HasPrefix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that the string to be found (`MY_CONST`) will be at the beginning of the `current_string`, then the most efficient way will be `HasPrefix`

> `func HasPrefix(s, prefix string) bool`
>
> HasPrefix tests whether the string s begins with prefix.

https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#HasPrefix

```
if strings.HasPrefix(current_string, MY_CONST){
   // do smth 
}
```

For simple tasks, like matching one exact substring (especially a prefix), string functions are generally faster than regexps.